# SQL Query assistance needed

Tags: mysql, sql

What part of this query is wrong?

```
Select COUNT ORDER_ID 
FROM customer_orders_delivery 
WHERE delivery_status_code LIKE 'Dispatched%' 'Processing%'
```

Could you please help fix it.

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed. It's definitely not "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical" and it can definitely be "reasonably answered". Maybe it's too specific, but this is the kind of question I think *should* be on stack overflow as it's example may help other newbies in SQL

Comment: "Not a real question" was probably the wrong way to close it, but I could certainly see it being re-closed as too localized, `*shrug*`

Comment: I suspect that it was closed as OP has not described what they intended the SQL to do, however there are obvious syntax problems with the SQL that can be fixed so voting to reopen.

Comment: Hmm, surely this would have been reasonably closed as having demonstrated no prior effort? I'm fully in favour of helping beginners, but we need to combat help vampires too. Richard, we generally like to see what you've tried - partly because we want to help beginners learn, and partly so we avoid doing other people's work/homework for them `:)`

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if the statement is intended to do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(order_id) 
  FROM customer_orders_delivery
 WHERE delivery_status_code LIKE 'Dispatched%'
    OR delivery_status_code LIKE 'Processing%'
```

`COUNT()` is an aggregate function, we expect there to be open and close parens around an expression, e.g.  `COUNT(1)`,  `COUNT(*)`, `COUNT(order_id)`

The rest of the syntax looks okay, up to the literal `'Processing%'`. A literal is not valid there. It looks as if the query is intended to return rows where that column starts with `'Dispatched'` or that column starts with `'Processing'`.